# How to find where is a text is called React whole folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

there is a file that i'm working with and the issue is that I want to find where in the entire react app are the instances where the logo file is called. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried finding the direct file path of the svg image

Answer (score 0):

You can do Edit, Find in Files (or Ctrl+Shift+F ) default key binding, Cmd+Shift+F on MacOS) to search the Currently open Folder.